# Boolean "not equal to" in Lua (negation of a Boolean conditional)

Tags: if-statement, lua, boolean, negation

How do I write an `if` statement in Lua that negates (inverts/flips) a Boolean variable used as the condition?

For example, in Java, one can write:

```java
boolean a;
a = false;
if (!a) {
    //do something
}
```

I tried to replicate the above Java code in Lua using the following:

```lua
local a
a = false
if (~a) then
    -- do something
end
```

However, I received an error. How do I write the Lua equivalent of the above Java snippet?

Comment: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.4

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Lua uses mostly keywords. Use `not a` instead of `~a`.